# JQuery gives error parsing JSON after upgrade from 1.8.3 to 1.11.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am upgrading version of jQuery. Previously it was 1.8.3 and I am upgrading it to 1.11.2. But I am getting an issue while parsing JSON.

In 1.8.3 version I was using `$.parseJSON()` but after upgrading version of jQuery it's giving me an error that 'unexpected token u' in JSON at (position 0) jQuery.

If I am reverting back the version change it is working fine. How I can parse JSON for jQuery version 1.11.2?

Comment: what is json reponse you are trying to parse .. can you give a sample

Comment: Take a look at this [parseJSON in 1.9.0 is different from earlier versions](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/parsejson-in-1-9-0-is-different-from-earlier-versions)

Comment: Although @jcubic 's idea will probably work, you would have much better chances to an useful answer if you actually post the not working code here. It is also a requirement if you ask for debugging help.

Comment: The `unexpected u` error usually comes from an `undefined` cast to a string. Double check that the input variable is correct ^^